# want to keep scheme (http/https) as the same in Javascript fetch() with relative path

Tags: javascript, html

Please consider the following short code as javascript in the browser.

```
fetch('/api/example', {
    method: 'POST', 
    body: JSON.stringify({"x":"x"}),
}).then((response)=>{})
```

The page is calling from https://domain.name url however, fetch function call to http://domain.name/api/example which result in **Mix Content** error

how to solve this problem

**Note:** absolute url is not possible

Answer (score 0):

You can leave off the protocol, but include the domain name, like this...

```
fetch('//domain.name/api/example',
```

This is called a Protocol Relative URL. It will then just match the protocol of the original request.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#prurl

Comment: It's keep downgrade to http, I don't event know how come.

Comment: Is it possible the API service itself is redirecting HTTPS to HTTP? Perhaps try using curl just to confirm that HTTPS requests work correctly for this API server.
Using the protocol relative URL should work. If it's not, there must be a problem with the configuration of the API server.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I just checking API server find out that Redirect 307 occur and change https to http during that remove trail "/" from url will prevent that (FastAPI)